# How to remove firefox-dev (developer edition) icon from ubuntu launcher?

Tags: unity, firefox, icons, launcher

I installed the firefox developer edition from the **.tar.bz2** file by following instructions of the given link - https://medium.com/@js_debugger/how-to-install-firefox-developer-edition-on-ubuntu-1c7f5f2b6883. After a few days, I tried to uninstall the dev edition by running  `sudo apt remove firefox-dev && sudo apt purge firefox-dev`.
The terminal output showed that it was uninstalled and purged successfully but the problem is there is still the **firefox-dev icon** present because I ran the following commands beforehand

```
: cat > ~/.local/share/applications/firefoxDeveloperEdition.desktop <<EOL
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Firefox Developer Edition
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox
Icon=/opt/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;Favorite;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml_xml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp; X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow;NewIncognitos;
EOL
```

Please tell me what steps should I take **to remove the firefox-dev icon from the ubuntu launcher**.
I want to delete the icon on the left side (attached below).[The bluish icon] *https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnwZv.png*

Comment: Good job providing the link you used to install it! That helps a lot. The apt commands should have done nothing, since apt does not understand tarballs. Check that the files you installed to /opt (steps 4, 7, 9, 11) are really deleted. Also remember to restore your $PATH in your ~/.bashrc (steps 12, 13). In Step 15, you created a file `~/.local/share/applications/firefoxDeveloperEdition.desktop`. Delete that file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for solving my issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Step 15, you created a desktop file specifically so the software would show up in your launcher: `~/.local/share/applications/firefoxDeveloperEdition.desktop`

Simply delete that file:

`rm ~/.local/share/applications/firefoxDeveloperEdition.desktop`